# How to get entities that have a collection and one element of this collection in another collection

Tags: many-to-many, hql, join

Now I am trying to implement a function like filter. There are two models User and Role. I used unidirection many-to-many relationship. Below is my code.

```
    public class User {
        ...
        @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
        private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
        ...
    }

    public class Role {
        private String role;
        ...
    }
```

Now I want to get users who have many roles but exactly just one of the user's roles in the role collection that the user is picked out. I want to use HQL to query but I don't how to so I write a sql "select * from user as u left join user_role as ur on u.id = ur.user_id
where ur.role_id in (1,2)". But the result couldn't be converted to be a list of user. And I still need to use HQL, so does anyone can give some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The translation of your SQL query is

```
select u from User u join u.roles role 
where role.id in (1,2)
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql) to learn about HQL and joins.

Comment: Thanks very much! With your advice I worked it out:"select distinct u from User u join u.roles role with role.id in (2,3)"